# detect change when back to screen react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using **react-native-router-flux** for navigation. I am using **Action.ScreenKeyName** to go to the next screen and for back using **Actions.pop()**. When I go back to the previous screen then I want to reload all the content or data.

unfortunately **componentDidMount,componentWillUnmount** Only call first time load of the screen.

I also used AppState but It's working only for when App goto Background or foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before, here is my solution, maybe its not the best but you could take it a  try:

Adding a refresh after `Actions.pop()` or `Actions.popTo()` function with random key to `rerender` it using `setTimeout`.

```js
Actions.pop(); // Or Actions.popTo("SceneName");
setTimeout(() => {
      Actions.refresh({ key: Math.random() });
}, 100);
```

Hope it could helps.